# How can I create a counter using React.js JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I would like to know how to program the counter that can be found on the site [Site](http://www.worldometers.info/fr/) start when I open my application page

I m using mongodb for my databases how can I add it in my document

```
{
        "id": "P5",
        "nom": "Tata",
        "prenom": "Toto",
        "birth_date": "2020-10-10T07:00:00.000+00:00",
        "counter": 100
    }
```

Comment: what's problem?

Comment: How can I create a counter like that can be found on the site http://www.worldometers.info/fr/ the counter start when I open my page form add stop when I submitted my form and add the result in databases

Comment: see [repository](https://github.com/nimaa77/youtube-react-context) . it's help you.

Comment: @a-r-seif That is my question

Comment: ok.What I understand is that you are saying to create a project. But in this repository there is a counter example

Comment: Yes counter like time started and stoped automatically  , Start when I open form page and stope when i submitted the form and added the result in databases how can I create it using reactjs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223583/discussion-between-a-r-seif-and-rima).